# User Account locking\unlocking audit logs not coming in WSO2 5.3.0 audit.log

Tags: wso2, audit-logging, mdc

Account locking\unlocking audit logs not coming in WSO2 5.3.0 audit.log.
I tried below scenarios and didn't see any corresponding log in audit.log file:
1.Make 3 incorrect login attempts
2. Wait for 5 minutes ( keep user account idle )
3. Lock the User account from Wso2 Portal(admin account)
4. UnLock the User Account from Wso2 Portal(admin account)